# Solution for Ajax and Firefox issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox

I have gone through many posts but could not find a possible solution for this issue except giving `async:false`but i want the ansynchronous call to the fucntion in my Controller class. My ajax call works fine in IE and chrome but Firefox misses the ajax call.

```
$("#save_btn").on('click',function(event
    $.ajax({                                
          url: '<c:url value="/start/social" />' ,                          
          data: $('input,select',"#requestForm").not(".hint").serialize(),
          type: 'get',
          cache: false,               
            });
        });
```

My form looks like this

```
<form:form id="requestForm"  method="get" name="myForm" modelAttribute="startbean"  ACTION="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/start/questions" > 
.
.
.
</form:form>
```

But i want to use only ansynchronous call to the url in ajax call.

Is there a solution till now found to resolve the firefox and ajax issue??

I have been also looking around the Spring MVC: Servlet 3, Async Support but first i need to confirm if this issue has been resolved or not?

Comment: Do you have a specific problem with the code? To avoid the standard form submission you can simply hook to the `submit` event of the form and call `preventDefault()` on the event passed to the function.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan but that would prevent the Ansynchronous call to url in Ajax and until the request is complete it would not go to next page

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan there is no problem with the code ...it just does not work with firefox

Comment: You seem confused as to the purpose of AJAX. What's the point of an async request if you're transferring page anyway? Also, if it's not working in FF I'd say that's a problem :) Have you checked the console for errors in FF?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes i checked the FF console it shows the error that its not sending the GET request to the requested URL ' url: '<c:url value="/start/social" />'' '

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can you give any solution?

Comment: It got resolved when i upgraded the firefox to v50